# How to prevent scrollView from updating

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have an activity in Android with a scrollView. The scrollView displays a fixed layout with several items (text, more layouts, iamges, etc). When the activity is loaded I display the layout and start downloading an image - when the image is downloaded, I display it inside the scrollView by adding it in a RelativeLayout which is at the beginning/top of the main layout.

The Relative layout has its height set to WRAP_CONTENT, so before the image is displayed, its height is zero; when the image is added to it, it resizes to the image's height. The problem is that if the user scrolls down before the image is loaded and the image's RelativeLayout is off the screen, the top Y of the scrollView changes and the content moves down (this causes a distraction to the person looking a the content).

To fix this, I get the height of the image that is downloaded, check if the image is off the screen and if so, I adjust the scrollView top by calling `scrollView.scrollBy(0, imageHeight);` This corrects the problem but it cases a short 'flickering' of the screen between the two actions, e.g., adding the image to the layout (content moving down) and adjusting the scrollView top (content going back to original position). Here is the code that 'fixes' the scrollview position:

```
public void imageLoaded(final ImageView img) {
        img.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int imgHeight = img.getMeasuredHeight();

        // image is loaded inside a relative layout - get the top
        final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) img.getParent();
        final int layoutTop = parent.getTop();

        // adjust the layout height to show the image
        // 1. this changes the scrollview position and causes a first 'flickering'
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, imgHeight);
        parent.setLayoutParams(params);

        // adjust scrollbar so that the current content position does not change
        // 2. this corrects the scrollview position but causes a second 'flickering'
        // scrollY holds the scrollView y position (set in the scrollview listener)
        if (layoutTop < scrollY)
            scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    scrollview.scrollBy(0, imgHeight);
                }
            });

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

What I need to correct this is a way to disable screen updates or scrollView updates before the loading/adjustment process and enable it after.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: programmers are better at reading source codes. ;p

Comment: Added code that shows the adjustment process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was because the call to the scrollView.scrollBy was called from a thread. Removing it solved the problem. Here is the correct code:

```
public void imageLoaded(final ImageView img) {
        img.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int imgHeight = img.getMeasuredHeight();

        // image is loaded inside a relative layout - get the top
        final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) img.getParent();
        final int layoutTop = parent.getTop();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, imgHeight);
        parent.setLayoutParams(params);

        if (layoutTop < scrollY)
            scrollview.scrollBy(0, imgHeight);

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```